# allow a server side ReactJS app to respond client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've managed to successfully get ReactJS to work on the server side, but i'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around getting my client side to respond.

Like I need to turn everything on or something. I'm not grabbing data via ajax or anything, any data is in JSON in the components themselves.

I see lots of textual advice, but no exact code of how to get it to work.
Also, I'm using react router.

---

Additional background, I'm using commonJS and grunt to compile it. I include the compiled JS in my html file. When i click buttons and such, nothing happens.

Server:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var routes = require('./src/routes');

var app = Express();

app.use('/dist', Express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.use(function (req, res) {
    // pass in `req.url` and the router will immediately match
    Router.run(routes, req.url, function (Handler) {
        var content = React.renderToString(React.createElement(Handler, null));
        var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html', {encoding: 'utf8'});
        res.send(index.replace('%%%content%%%', content));
    });
});

var server = app.listen(9001, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})
```

router:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;

//TODO: dynamically load each route somehow...
var App = require('./app');
var Home = require('./home');
var ItemInstance = require('./item-instance');
var Todo = require('./todo');
var Task = require('./task');
var Project = require('./project');
var Workspace = require('./workspace');

var routes = (
    <Route name="index" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route name="home" path="/home" handler={Home} />
        <Route name="workspace" path="/workspace" handler={Workspace} />
        <Route name="instanceitem" path="/:tag/:id" handler={ItemInstance} />
        <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: Unless you've got JavaScript that runs on the client, it would just be static HTML. Your initial page needs to run the router, render, etc. Search for isomorphic react samples with react router.

Comment: I was under the assumption that I simply needed to connect the html to React or something, and not have to re-render. One of the benefits of Isomorphic is to not have to render on the client-side on first load [obviously to speed things up and alleviate battery consumption].

I've done a lot of googling on the subject and can't find any decent guide. All I find are tutorials using 5 other seemingly unnecessary tools, or github repositories with hundreds of files.

Comment: The render code is still executed as it attempts to connect with the DOM that was already pre-rendered on the server.

Comment: I managed to get things isomorphic, but I used a completely different routing solution. I'll post my solution once I've refined it a bit.

Thanks for your help WirePrairie. I dug deeper in my searches and found an older example of getting react isomorphism, which was simple enough for me. I need to update a lot of things, but it worked.